# How to get specific element inside of element stored in variable?

Tags: javascript, dom, methods

I am looking for way to select element inside of already located element in variable. For example I have selected a container:

```js
let productAttachedFilesModal = document.getElementById('modal_more_information');
```

I know, that inside are array of `a` elements, which I want to select as well. Which method should I use? in jQuery there are method `find()`. So I need the analog for JS.
Or I need to use DOM method again? Like this:

```js
let listOfLinks= document.getElementById('modal_more_information > a');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways:

```
let anchors = productAttachedFilesModal.getElementsByTagName("a");

let anchors = document.querySelectorAll("#modal_more_information > a")

let anchors = productAttachedFilesModal.querySelectorAll("a");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `productAttachedFilesModal.children` to get its children, which is the elements inside. It will get you an array of HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can just query that stored DOM reference:

```
let productAttachedFilesModal = document.getElementById('modal_more_information');

// Query the stored DOM element for all descendent anchors
let childAnchors = productAttachedFilesModal.querySelectorAll("a");
```